# How to make a link by helpers in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC. I created a login form and created two text boxes, then I used requirements attributes for them that if the were empty or wrong make errors.
Also I created a button link by `@Html.ActionLink("", "")` helper, so when I click it, without checking the validation of text boxes goes to next page. Would you please help me how can I fix this problem?

[view code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVJCz.png)
[controller code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHsNn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("CheckLogin", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
        {

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username, null, new { @class = "required", @style = "color : red" })
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">


                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.username, null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter User Name" })

                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userpassword, null, new { @class = "required", @style = "color : red" })
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">


                @Html.PasswordFor(model=>model.userpassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Password" })

                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
            </div>


        }



 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

i think you simply copy and paste it

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkname", "Action name", "controller name")
```

and link is created .

Comment: I can create a link.but my problem is when I click on this it goes to the next page.whether textboxes are correct or wrong.i want to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok,I'll write in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using Asp.Net Core you can use built-in tag builders:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="<Controller name>" asp-action="<action name>" asp-route-<parameterName>="<parameter value>">Click Me!</a>
```

`btn btn-primary` is a bookstrap class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a form in order to get correct validation

```
@model yourmodel
@using (Html.BeginForm("..", "...", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     ...
    // your fields here now like 
    @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.prop)
    @Html.ValidationFor(m=>m.prop)

    //your submit button here
   <input type=submit>

}
```

and at the end of the page don't forget to include Jquery validation scripts

Comment: sorry for lateing I upload image of my code, because have alittle problem in the site,sorry.images are in the main question.

Comment: remove ActionLink and give controller and action parameters in the @html.BeginForm , make your button as input field of type submit